# Corona SDK getting network response

Tags: http, networking, get, request, coronasdk

I must be able to interface with a servlet that is in the network address of the request and take the result of this request but does not work

Code:

```
function onLoginBtnRelease(event)
        network.request( "http://localhost/foodingame/searchPlayer?userName="..utente.text.."&password="..password.text, "GET", networkListener )
    end


    local function networkListener( event )

      if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!")
      else
       local myNewData = event.response
        print ("From server: "..myNewData)
       local decodedData = (json.decode( myNewData))
       if(decodedData.find(utente.text)) then
            messaggio.text = "Persona trovata"
            else
            messaggio.text = "Persona non trovata"
        end
     end
    end
```

Comment: Please explain what does not work.

Comment: Virtually the site if the user exists will return the user name
but when he tries to search inside decodedData the end it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the networkListener function before you can use it. Simply flip the order of the functions.